# How do I open Localdb SQL ProjectV12

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

Short question: I have a visual studio 2015 database project. In my solution. I am using the database first approach for handling my datalayer. How do I open the actual database for management. I can not seem to find any type of SQL server database management tool.

Long question: I am creating a visual studio 15 web application. I am using the visual studio database project for creating and managing the database schema. I was able to create the database during the database compare and update. My server name was "(localdb)\ProjectsV12". I was also able to create my entities from the database. So I know the database exists somewhere. I have never installed anything more than the SQL server express on my local box (I usually use Azure SQL).

According to the error log it is a Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) ,Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 (Build 10240: )

I also have a windows 10 box running Visual Studio 15. So where is the sql management tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The localDB is only for development

it can be accessed from server explorer in VS2015 --> Data Connections

connect to server "(localdb)\ProjectsV12" and your DB name

[image: (localdb)\ProjectsV12]

Comment: Thank you very much.  I forgot all about that it can be accessed via visual studio.  Bone head mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that you can have multiple SqlLocalDB instances installed on your computer and you can list them by opening up a CMD Window and executing the following command

```
sqllocaldb versions
```

For your reference:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Server Explorer probably gives you all you need, but note you can also connect to localdb from SQL Server Management Studio ([download](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx)), which is the de facto standard for managing SQL Server databases.